# How to know what user belongs to what ip on debian

Tags: debian, ip, users

is there a way to get an overview of users logged in on my server and the ip they are connecting from ?

I have the IP already, I want the user that is associated with it :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`w`

Comment: wow, as simple as one letter

Comment: +1 for the smallest, valid answer ever.

Comment: @SmallClanger - smallest ever, and smallest possible :)

Comment: I tried, but it wouldn't let me put less than 30 characters in.

Comment: I think @jscott used a sly comment to pad his answer out.

Comment: I would like to flag this answer as 'awesome'

Answer (score 11):

Use the `who` command.  It lists everyone logged in, their terminal and their source hostname/ip address.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to w and who,
last - recent logins with ips
lastlog - list of all users with the last ip they were logged in from

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `w`<sup>[1](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?w)</sup> and `who`<sup>[2](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?who)</sup>, you may also look at `finger`<sup>[3](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?finger)</sup>.