# See all logged in users on Debian server

Tags: ssh, debian, user-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know what user belongs to what ip on debian](https://serverfault.com/questions/302026/how-to-know-what-user-belongs-to-what-ip-on-debian)

Is there a way to see a list of all current logged in user on a Debian server?
Sometimes it is very useful to do so, e.g. before updating certain plugins etc.

Any software or built-in features? All users will log in through ssh.

Comment: what do you mean with Debain Apache server? Do you want to know the system users or users which are currently visiting a website?

Comment: I'm sorry that was a bit inaccurate. I mean a debian server, and users who are logged into that server. Edited post.

Comment: [Sounds familiar](http://serverfault.com/questions/302026/how-to-know-what-user-belongs-to-what-ip-on-debian).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the `who` command. It will show you the username and the terminal/pseudo terminal that they are using, as well as what time they logged in:

```
    migs     pts/0        2012-02-15 17:46 (:0)
    migs     pts/1        2012-02-15 17:46 (:0)
    migs     pts/2        2012-02-15 17:48 (:0)
```

Mine shows three instances of me because I've got two terminal windows open, plus my log-in to the box.

You could also use the `last` command. This will show the most recently logged in people, as well as currently logged in users.

```
    migs     pts/2        :0               Wed Feb 15 17:48   still logged in   
    migs     pts/1        :0               Wed Feb 15 17:46   still logged in   
    migs     pts/0        :0               Wed Feb 15 17:46   still logged in
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know such commands existed. Does the 'last' command have a limit or will it print out all users who have ever logged in?

Comment: it will display all log-ins from up to the date the /var/log/wtmp file got rotated. You can check the other wtmp files in /var/log with the -f switch.

Answer (score 3):

The `who` command will do the job and show all users logged in.

Comment: Migs answer was a little more accurate. Anyway, thanks!